# Wordpress jQuery .val statement error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, input, meta-boxes

I can´t solve my issue with the jQuery .val(). I want to spice up, the site creation functions on my website and there I have several metaboxes to choose header layout and so on. There I want to show or hide metaboxes based on my choices. I´ll get an error in line 18 and have no idea how to solve it...

It´s difficult to explain, so created a simple Fiddle. It would be really nice, if someone can take a short look on the code. Thanks a lot!

[Fiddle]

```
[Fiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/Blackzet/2Lr2g09p/1/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten the dollar sign ($) in a few places:

```
else if ($(this).val()=="masthead" && ("#_zet_titel_layout").val()=="show_zet_title") {
```

has to be:

```
else if ($(this).val()=="masthead" && $("#_zet_titel_layout").val()=="show_zet_title") {
```

Comment: Oh my god... I´m stupid.. Thanks a lot for your help! Nice greetings!